# In Azure pipeline - how to build docker image with multiple image tags

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, acr

- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
  containerRegistry: 'my-registry'
  repository: '$(System.TeamProject)/$(Build.Repository.Name)'
  command: 'buildAndPush'
  Dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
  tags: |
  $(Build.SourceVersion)
  $(Build.SourceBranchName)

is it possible to do multiple tags for one image build?

Need to add multiple image tag for one docker build in azure pipelines

Answer (score 2):

your question contains the answer:

```
tags: |
  $(Build.SourceVersion)
  $(Build.SourceBranchName)
  more_tags_go_here
```